# Time travel short story where a few people travel in a house and experience a large subjective duration

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

As the title says, I am looking for a short story I read probably one to two years ago. It's about three people volunteering for a scientific experiment concerning time travel. In it, they travel inside a house or rather the house travels with them through time. The catch is that although they only travel a few seconds or minutes, they experience a huge time span. This leads to one of them going crazy after looking outside for a while (I think it was just static outside but he saw something in there) and going outside. The other two remain inside but as the time does not seem to pass at all, they decide to look outside too in order to pass the time more quickly (I believe there was a passage about one of them looking outside briefly and the other one worrying as for them days pass). In the end they finally get back, the one who went outside killing themselves (?). Further research was cancelled afterwards.

I hope this description helps, sadly I could not find anything using multiple search engines, no matter the wording.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Did you read this a book or magazine or online?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! This was online, although I do not remember where exactly.

Comment: It's not "[Life, the universe and everything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life,_the_Universe_and_Everything) is it? Flying house and time-travel are both in the book, but I don't know that the house time-travels.

Answer (score 2):

I spent a fair bit of time looking for it as well as it seems many of the links have been removed but I found it on Reddit.

"[Time Travel Is Not What You Think It's Like](https://www.reddit.com/r/nosleep/comments/an0s3x/time_travel_is_not_what_you_think_its_like/)" ([part 2](https://www.reddit.com/r/nosleep/comments/anq3zt/time_travel_is_not_what_you_think_its_like_part_2/)) by u/flard published March 2019

> My name is Clark. I am one of three people who can truthfully say they have time traveled. It is not what you think it’s like.

....

> As we got off the bus one-by-one, we could see that in the center of the clearing was a building. It had a one very large window on one side, basically encompassing that entire wall. Every other wall was black on the outside, and I could see through the window that the inside was painted white.

....

> “You will be launching 3 hours into the future. Once activated at the control site, this building will disappear. My team and I will be on standby for three hours, then, poof—the house is back with all of you in it, three hours into the future.”

> The other realization was about that void. Ryan had been staring off into it for the entirety of our stay, save for the first couple of minutes. He has not moved. He has not blinked. Sometimes he mumbles something about time or the universe, but most of it is gibberish. Emma and I decided that maybe something is in there. We can’t see it, but Ryan can, and it’s driving him insane. We decided it’s best not to look at it for too long.

....

> He reached his hand out into the void. It looked like an optical illusion. Exactly where the door frame was, as soon as he broke through that plane, his hand disappeared. All I could see was his wrist with nothing attached.
>
> He brought his arm back inside the room.
>
> His hand was missing. There was exposed bone, flesh, and tissue. But he did not bleed. He did not scream.
>
> He smiled.
>
> He then walked out into the void, looking like a ghost walking through a wall.

....

> Before I could begin to process what was happening, Ryan screamed louder than I thought physically possible. I jumped and started to back away, but Emma didn’t even flinch. Ryan grabbed the lamp from the table, smashed it on the ground, picked up a large piece of glass, and pushed it through his chest and into his heart. His hands were bleeding and his chest was discharging blood by the pint. He died within a minute.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you please include some quotes from this link so it's possible to see the actual answer?  Reddit especially is no longer a stable source, so anything relevant there should be quoted.